# Where is Django's admin read-only permission for models?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication

I've read at [How can I MODIFY django to create "view" permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336382/how-can-i-modify-django-to-create-view-permission) that Django 1.2 cames with a read-only permission for admin models. Where I set this option? It's not found as a permission in the auth app.

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.1/#what-s-new-in-django-2-1

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the steps outlined in the linked answer. The 1.2 feature mentioned in the article concerns adding the `editable=False` option to a model's field which renders the field non-editable in the admin interface for all users.

If you really are missing this functionality i suggest opening a ticket on the django support site to have this fix added to django however remember that the django admin site is for ADMINS. It is not designed to be used as A CRUD interface for all users, just an administrative interface for diving into the data and editing it in place. It's only over time that people have been adding more and more User friendly enhancements to it.

Comment: In the original question seems like the original problem was solved in Django 1.2 but it actually looks that OTHER problem was solved.