# django admin readonly data (no edit, no add)

Tags: django, django-admin

admin.py

```
class ChatMessageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    list_display = ('username','ip', 'timestamp','message',)
    search_fields = ['message']
    list_filter = ('username','ip')

admin.site.register(ChatMessage,ChatMessageAdmin)
```

when I rewrite `has_change_permission` method like upper I can't see the http://[domain]/admin/chat page which shows all the chat entries
How can I rewrite `has_change_permission` to have access to this page?

**Edit**
I don't the auth_user can edit the chat entry, but if he wants I want to have the ability to delete it.

Comment: Try using `readonly_fields` without using `has_change_permission`.

Comment: @arulmr if i do this the auth_user should see the entries detailed (change_form.html)..
For some reason i don't want this :( Also i think that's not sound's as a good solution because the user will see a save button

Comment: @arulmr i think that's what i am looking for.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336382/how-can-i-modify-django-to-create-view-permission