# django admin application list in readonly

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-tools, django-admin-actions

In django-admin, we have 3 rules that we can attribute to a table we can add, modify and delete. When you choose for an user the rule of modify, he can't add and delete.

My problem is that a have list of object and I don't want that the user be able to modify but only choose.

How I can disable it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's complicated.

django-**admin** as the name suggests is intended for **admins**, who should be able to edit, delete and make new tables.

Maybe this topic will be helpful for you:

https://github.com/lambdalisue/django-permission/issues/67

[View permissions in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104449/view-permissions-in-django)